# How I can print information from class?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Here my awful code:

```
import socket

class tcp_server():
    connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    connection.bind(('localhost', 32767)) 
    connection.listen(10) 
    recieve_frame_buffer = [] 

    def send_frame(self, frame):
        self.connection.send(bytes(frame, encoding='utf-8'))

    def recieve_frame(self): 
        new_connect = self.connection.accept()
        address = self.connection.accept() 
        while True:
            data = new_connect.recv(1024) 
            self.recieve_frame_buffer.append(data) 
            if not data: 
                break

print(tcp_server(type).recieve_frame_buffer)
```

would last "print" work and if not, how I can fix it? I just need for him, to print a data that we get, every time that we get data. Using class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are trying to pass `type` into the `tcp_server`, but you have not setup any arguments for it.

Also, to use a class, you have to first create a `class object` like so:

```
serv = tcp_server()
print(serv.recieve_frame_buffer(# Add your 'frame' here.))
```

Also, you have not returned your data from the function. How do you expect to print it?